# Is this a case of Non-Repeatable Reads?

Tags: concurrency, isolation-level

I have the following tables (here modeled in Entity Framework, but my question has nothing to do with EF):

[image]

As you can see, this is a versioned `Product` table. The `Id` column is the primary key, but the combination `(EntityId, VersionId)` could be the primary key as well. `EntityId` denotes the Id of the entity which is constant between different versions of the entity. The entity gets deleted by writing a row with `IsDeleted = 1`.

The stored procedures that are responsible for data manipulation first check if the data operation is okay. For example, the UPDATE SP checks if the entity has already been deleted. If those checks succeed, the SPs generate a new row in the Version table, followed by a new row in the `Product` table:

```
(pseudo-code):

sp_Product_Update:
(1) IF EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Product WHERE IsDeleted = 1 AND EntityId = @ProductId)
        RAISERROR "Entity has already been deleted"
        RETURN
(2) INSERT INTO Versions ...
(3) INSERT INTO Product ... (IsDeleted = 0)

sp_Product_Delete:
(1) IF EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Product WHERE IsDeleted = 1 AND EntityId = @ProductId)
        RAISERROR "Entity has already been deleted"
        RETURN
(2) INSERT INTO Versions ...
(3) INSERT INTO Product ... (IsDeleted = 1)
```

This works all well.

Currently, I'm analyzing this for concurrency issues. Imagine the following concurrency scenario, where two SPs are invoked at the same time, for the same entity:

```
Transaction 1                          Transaction 2
sp_Product_Update                      sp_Product_Delete

(1) Check succeeds, entity has not yet been deleted.

                                       (1) Same check.

                                       (2) INSERT INTO Versions...
                                       (3) INSERT INTO Product.. (IsDeleted = 1)

(2) INSERT INTO Versions...
(3) INSERT INTO Product ... (IsDeleted = 0)
```

As you can see, this race condition leads to inconsistent data, namely an `IsDeleted = 0` row which comes **after** an `IsDeleted = 1` entry.

So we have to determine what level of isolation we need to avoid this race condition.

- This doesn't appear to be a **Dirty Read**, since the data that is read in (1) is not dirty.
- It's no **Non-Repeatable Read** either, there are no two reads in either transaction.
- Same goes for **Phantom Read**, there are no two queries in either transaction.

So I'm left with two questions:

- **Is my analysis correct?**
- **What isolation level is needed to avoid this kind of issue?**

Answer (score 1):

Your solution requires serializable isolation level as all commands need to be executed together as one atomic operation.

If you would not use stored procedures, I would encourage to use [optimistic locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) which is designed for this kind of situation with high throughput.

Comment: So there are other requirements which influence the isolation level? According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems), the **Serializable** isolation level just means that I won't get **Dirty Reads**, **Non-Repeatable Reads** nor **Phantom Reads**. How can I know that **Serializable** prevents my issue?